# How to incorporate server side authentication in a react-redux project with python/django backend?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a project which has it's backend on python/django and front end in react and redux with client side routing using react-router. Please suggest me some ways of doing user login authentication/validation in react with the django token generated/stored at the backend. The login flow should be something like this:

1. User table with email and password created in django, auth token generated by django.
2. User logs in for the first time, api gets called by react, on successful validation server responds with a token which I'll be storing in a session. All the subsequent calls to the api will include this token for authorization.

Secondly, I'm confused about how the secured client side routes will be authorised? On the basis of the user logged in state or what?

PS: I'm only asking suggestions for the best ways to achieve this and nothing else.

Comment: The client-side routing isn't really "secured" in that sense. You have to assume that a user could potentially reach every single client-side route your React app has to offer. Someone could just reverse-engineer your javascript bundle to gain this information. What is secured however is the underlaying API calls to the backend, which only expose data if the requests are coming from an authenticated source (which holds the token you described). Having said that, you still do client-side checks for authentication of course, in case a user loses their token for whatever reason.

Comment: I recently did something similar. Once your user is authenticated, and token received, I would keep that token in the store (with a short expiration). Then check for the user's token on every route change request, in addition to API requests as described by @timotgl What are you using as a router solution? React-Router?

Comment: @flybear Yes I'm using react router only.

Answer (score 0):

With this a year old, you may not need this, but maybe others could use it. I ran into a similar problem and wrote a package so I wouldn't have to keep writing authentication for django...

[drf-redux-auth](https://github.com/jamstooks/drf-redux-auth)

It's just provides actions, reducers, and basic (example) components for authenticating with Django Rest Framework using token authentication.

I'd be interested to hear how you decided to handle the authorization piece with react-router...